# Is there a way of seeing the script code for an action I have performed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am new to writing scripts in Google Apps. I am trying to script various actions in Google Docs which previously I would have done through the main user interface. Is there a way of "recording" such actions as they are carried out, analogous to recording a Macro in Excel?

For example, I am creating a Form in Google Docs. Using the main interface, I can add an Image item and upload an image from another source (Google Drive, my desktop, etc.), but I can't work out the script code that would perform this same action. Is there any way to output the script that would have carried out the same action that I have just performed?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you cannot 'record' a macro.

There is an issue in the Issue tracker [(issue 650)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=650) where Google have mentioned that it is not feasible at the moment (Jul 2010). You may star the issue to register your interest to the enhancement request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real issue is that the GApps scripting functions are manipulations of the underlying object model of the document. The UI also manipulates the underlying object model, but no one has yet created the functions to emulate the UI in GApps script form. Recording the actions would then be a separate step and converting the recorded actions into GApps functions would be yet another step.

So you need to be clear: is your goal to be able to record and play back UI actions, or is your goal to be able to upload an image into a GDoc? You asked about recording and that's the answer you got. Maybe if you asked about how to use GApps to add an image to a GDoc, you would get a more useful answer.

My own personal question would be:

> I haven't figured out how to use the GApps documentation very
>   efficiently yet. I do a lot of fruitless hunting. How do I find in the
>   docs how to add an image to a GDoc?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Srik answer was perfect. Op wants to record a macro. People want technology to be simple. Almost nobody really wants to be a programmer.